# Sending emails with JSP and Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, email, jsp, spring-mvc, html-email

Is it possible to design an email using JSP to be sent through Spring 3.0's JavaMailSender mechanism?  JavaMailSender probably has little to do with this question, but the idea is to take advantage of JSP's `<fmt:message key="phrasetitle"/>` internationalization mechanism, its variable/loop JSTL code and allow designers to easily hand me completed html emails.

Additionally, I could make a webpage that imports this JSP so that I can easily provide a link in each email to be able to view that email on the web in case their client doesn't see the html properly.

***UPDATE***: The 2 answers below suggest using Velocity for email instead of JSP, so it seems like that's the smart choice.  However, just some quick scanning of stackoverflow suggests FreeMarker might be better suited for my needs.  In particular I want to be able to have a JSP page which mirrors what's sent out in email.  I'll have to translate the code from JSP to Velocity or FreeMarker, but the advantage FreeMarker gives me is I can reuse a lot of the JSP code, particularly taglibs.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSP is not a templating technology. For that for example [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) is a better choice.

If you really insist in using JSP, then you have got to execute it locally by [`java.net.URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://localhost:8080/context/mailtemplate.jsp").openStream();
```

Comment: seems so inefficient to call the URL, there isn't any way to do this within code and not through http?

Comment: Yes, use a templating technology. JSP isn't. It's a web/HTTP oriented view technology.

Comment: Updated my question, does it make sense to use FreeMarker so I can reuse a lot of the JSP code even if I can't do a complete import?

Comment: Yes, that's also a good option. Velocity was just the first templating engine which came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

There's some [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html) about using Velocity which will do what you want.  I use it to handle emails in Spring and it works great.

What I typically do is to have an EmailService which which I call from a Controller whose job is to take care of sending emails.  Methods within that accept a Command Object, which is accessed in the velocity template and rendered as a String (the email body).  You can then use MailSender etc to send the mail.

Comment: Updated my question, does it make sense to use FreeMarker so I can reuse a lot of the JSP code even if I can't do a complete import?

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree that Velocity or Freemarker may be a better choice, if you really need to render a JSP and capture the output as a String (which you could pass to a JavaMailer), check out my tutorial on [Capturing JSP Output](http://technologicaloddity.com/2011/10/04/render-and-capture-the-output-of-a-jsp-as-a-string/)

It uses Spring 3, and also allows use of fmt:message, fmt:formatNumber, and spring:message.  The idea is basically to use the RequestDispatcher.include method to render the page into a MockHttpServletRequest.

Comment: Very nice, I ended up going with Velocity though.